# iOS - How to create recurring calendar events with exclusion occurrences (date)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, events, recurrence, repeat

I'm trying to create a recurrent event into calendar through JSON API,  but with exclusion occurences (/date) I don't know how to do it. I think i create a recurrent event, then I delete occurences.

update:
For example, the event repeats every weekend. However, I removed some of the weekends from the time line, creating an exception to a recurrence rule.
How can I get these excluded dates through the API?

my code:
 1. CreateEvent from api json:

```
NSDictionary *dicEvent = [self.arrayEvents objectAtIndex:index];

EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.title = [dicEvent objectForKey:@"RecurrenceRule"];
[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
event.startDate = [dicEvent objectForKey:@"startDate"];
event.endDate =  [dicEvent objectForKey:@"endDate"];
    EKSpan span = EKSpanFutureEvents;

[self.eventStore saveEvent:self.savedEvent span:span commit:YES error:&error];


2. then with exclusion occurrences, I think I delete occurences.
EventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:calendars];

NSArray *results =  [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
for (int i = 0; i < results.count; i++) {
 EKEvent *event = [results objectAtIndex:i]
 if ([event.occurencesIdentifier isEqualToString: eventoccurencesIdentifier]) {
    // delete occurencesIdentifier
break;
}
```

Please help me where I had gone wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some source code how you try to do this?

Comment: Yes, update my code + ideal.

Comment: @AntonVlasov: Would you have a suggestion? tks